# Formatting MySQL code in order to be able to submit a question

Tags: support, code-formatting

I can't make a post because Stack Overflow keeps insisting on some formatting, even though my code is already formatted.

This was a preview of my post. Notice how code is already "parsed" by Stack Overflow:

[image: Post preview screenshot]

It said that I need to use 4 spaces, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to make the indentation. I tried both and killed more time for these attempts than I invested in formulating the question, but no luck. I **tried** using *same* indentation for all lines of my code.

The error is:

**Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.**

---

The whole post is:

> I want to make a list of "events" and see list of correlated tags for
> each event. The thing is that tags stored in another table that
> connects tags with events via Many-To-Many relation
>
> These tables and fields are used in my example
>
> ```
> events.id
> events.title  
> events.city_id  
> tag_events.event_id
> tag_events.tag_id
> tags.id
> tags.title
> ```
>
> This is my attempt:
>
> ```
> SELECT
> events.id, 
> events.title,
> SELECT 
>   (GROUP_CONCAT(tags.title) 
>   FROM events 
>   LEFT JOIN tag_events ON events.id = tag_events.event_id 
>   JOIN tags ON tag_events.tag_id = tags.id) 'List of tags'
> FROM events
> WHERE events.city_id = 111
> GROUP BY events.id
> ```
>
> The result I get is list of events with same list of tags for each
> event (incorrect output) I don't know how to implement idea to connect
> "outer" SELECT statement with "included" SELECT statement via fiels
> tag_events.event_id

Comment: What is _“events.id events.title events.city\_id tag\_events.event\_id tag\_events.tag\_id tags.id tags.title”_ supposed to mean? Why do you have this there? Those are not English sentences. This looks like unformatted code. The `SELECT` keyword should be formatted as code. Each identifier or piece of code like `tag_events.event_id` should be formatted as code.

Comment: Since there's no quality check on meta, you will be able to post the original markdown on here without getting blocked, and perhaps help us to review the issues.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon
this is not whole post. My current question is not on the topic of using MYSQL, it is only about pasting blocks of code into the stack overflow website. You can see whole code block. What is written above the code is not relevant to the question whatsoever

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for the Idea, I will pose whole question here, in case I won't be able so solve this formatting issue to post on the original section of the website

Comment: @SebastianSimon
> Each identifier or piece of code like tag_events.event_id should be formatted as code.

Thanks, I did not know that. I thought I was supposed to mark as code only selected part

Comment: FI, there are [4 TABs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m33s) in it.

Answer (score 1):

- Put a blank line before and after the block of code.
- The block of code seems to have only 1 or 2 spaces at the beginning; make it 4.  If it is in a bullet list, make it 6 instead of 4.  Example

  ```
  SELECT iiiii, WWWWW
      FROM foobar;
  ```
- Use Edit to see what I typed.

Comment: Similarly backtics around `in-line code`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, the result is that I could not post my question because I had to outline all identifiers as code, not only the actual `SELECT` MySQL request.

Comment: Re *"I had to outline all identifiers as code"*: That sounds incidental. I am not convinced. There most be a canonical meta question somewhere.