# I miss the highlighting of code, etc

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I much prefer the colored highlighting that was applied to 'code' before about a week ago.

Is there a way to re-enable that?  Or configure the pages to work with a different CSS?  Or something else?

I feel that my answers are not as pointed when `code` does not stand out as much as it used to.  The coloring seems to have been removed.

Comment: What do you mean? What code is missing syntax highlighting?

Comment: Syntax highlighting works perfectly fine in Firefox Nightly 100.0a1. What browser are you using? Does it work without extensions? Is there an error in the browser console or the Network tab?

Comment: I didn't realize it had changed. Different colors are used for the same syntax highlighting now than were used a week ago? [This](https://cln.sh/0jvjOD) is not how you see "your answers" styled? (Dark mode notwithstanding)

Comment: Syntax highlighting colors have not been removed.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine - I found the coloring to be useful.  I am using Chrome 99.0.4844.74 .  I played with "accessibility", but thought I turned it all off.

Comment: Syntax highlighting has not been removed. See the linked screesnhot in my previous comment. Something may be wrong in your setup.

Comment: @SebastianSimon FWIW nightly builds of browsers are not officially supported because they are not officially released, so it is not particularly helpful to check on those browsers for if something is still working or not.

Comment: I am refering to "code" highlighting, not "syntax".

Comment: It's unclear what you refer to. Maybe if you provided a screenshot we would understand what's the problem exactly.

Comment: Seems to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/568m1.png

Comment: I think the issue is on Dark mode where the highlight for inline codes has too low contrast compared to the background, though I can't remember what it looked like before...

Comment: Maybe, @AndrewT. Yet, I can see inline code perfectly with dark mode (https://cln.sh/IGelOP). And the OP mentions "coloring", which seem to be more pertinent for multiline code blocks than for inline code formatting.

Comment: Is [Formatting MySQL code in order to be able to submit a question](/a/416746/4642212) related to this question?

Comment: @VLAZ - "code" is in a different font, but is only black on white; I was used to a hint of color instead of white.

Comment: @RickJames Did you see my screenshot? It shows the word "code" on a grey background. Is this what you see or not? Which browser are you on? Which theme do you use? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @VLAZ - No gray background.  I have been searching for "dark mode", but I have not found where it might be set.

Comment: @RickJames [Your profile settings](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Thanks for the link.  I don't remember being there.  Switching to System Settings (from Light), did not fix the problem.  So it must be somewhere in Ubuntu.

Comment: 8 downvotes -- You would rather chase me off than help me?  I'm willing to accept that I did something wrong, but it would be nice to get some help as to where I can fix it.

Comment: Without a screenshot, I'm afraid there isn't much to say here. As a shot in the dark, you do not happen to mean the code you see in t [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416746/1426539), don't you?

Comment: You are not providing the minimum for other users to be able to help you: a screenshot showing the issue, a link to a post where you experience it, etc. Worse, other users commented/answered with screenshots of their own, and you didn't say if these replicate or not your experience. For that, some users find the question "not useful", and probably voted accordingly.

Comment: @yivi - The screenshot picks up on the background color change -- _unlike_ what I see without the screenshot.  This just adds to the mystery.

Comment: More information that you could have provided in the question itself (with the screeshot itself, so other users could see what you meant). As in the main site, providing enough information to let other users help is crucial.

Comment: @yivi -  Sorry fo the ambiguity; I am referring to the single, inline, word "code" (highlighted: `code`) as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/568m1.png .

Comment: @RickJames Yes, what about it? Looks normal. That’s the [screenshot that VLAZ provided earlier](/questions/416743/4642212#comment900648_416743). You have yet to provide your own screenshot.

Comment: An inline piece of code with the text "code" (`code`) was never really highlighted in any special way AFAIK.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine It does have a grayish background. Maybe that's what the OP mean by "coloring".  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine - Yes, I miss the "grayish background".

Comment: @RickJames By the way, you still haven’t addressed two of my three questions from my first comment: _“Does it work without extensions? Is there an error in the browser console or the Network tab?”_

Comment: Re *"my answers are not as pointed"*: Can you [add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/416743/edit) an example of such an answer (not here in comments)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Comment: At the next upgrade of Ubuntu, the problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce this report. This is what your code looks like in your most recent answer in dark mode, which looks like it's working just fine, at least.

[image: screenshot of an answer showing clear code coloring/syntax highlighting in a dark-mode answer]

Be aware that sometimes you may need to explicitly state the language that needs to be used. If the system can't automatically detect which language it is, it won't apply any syntax highlighting. You can do this with the code fences (e.g. " ```` ```php ````") or the old-school method (`<!-- language: lang-php -->`).

Also keep in mind that when editing a post, the preview will lose syntax highlighting whenever you start typing or making changes. You'll need to stop and wait a few seconds for the syntax highlighting to show up in the preview again.